# Access kubernetes external IP from the internet

Tags: kubernetes, iptables, nginx-ingress

I am currently setting up a kubernetes cluster (bare ubuntu servers). I deployed metallb and ingress-nginx to handle the ip and service routing. This seems to work fine. I get a response from nginx, when I wget the externalIP of the ingress-nginx-controller service (works on every node). But this only works inside the cluster network. How do I access my services (the ingress-nginx-controller, because it does the routing) from the internet through a node/master servers ip? I tried to set up routing with iptables, but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong and is it the best practise ?

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -d <Servers IP> --dport 80 -j DNAT --to <ExternalIP of nginx>:80

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d <ExternalIP of nginx> --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

iptables -F
```

Here are some more information:

```
kubectl get services -n ingress-nginx

NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.103.219.111   198.51.100.1   80:31872/TCP,443:31897/TCP   41h
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.108.194.136   <none>         443/TCP                      41h
```

Please share some thoughts
Jonas

Comment: Could you provide Service and Ingress manifests? Also the output of `kubectl get services` and `kubectl get ing` might be useful.

Comment: I added the output of services in the ingress-nginx namespace. But I don´t think this is an ingress configuration problem. Everything works fine, when I call the ingress-nginx-controller by the external-Ip on the server. My problem is, to get it callable from outside the server. When using a kubernetes cluster on AWS or DO etc. this is preconfigured, but I build the cluster from bare Ubuntu maschines.

Comment: I need more explanation as for what are you trying to accomplish, are you trying to access the ingress-controller itself or do you have an app deployed and try to access the LoadBalancer connected to that Deployment?

Comment: Generally I am trying to access my service via my domain (resolved to the masters ip).
In my understanding, the loadbalancer (metallb) does the externalIP routing
(access the service from any participant in the network) and the ingress controller
does the webrouting (forwarding specific domain to service). So in order to
get a webresponse I need to forward the requests to the ingress controller.
This seems to work, because if I curl the nginx controller I get a 404 error
(the controller is responding and 404, because I dont have a default rule).

Comment: I am also able to access the ingress controller via the externalIP, from any
node or master. Therefore I think the loadbalancer also does the desired work.
This is all happening inside the cluster network. Now I want get a response,
when calling my domain. The domain resolves to my masters public IP address,
but there is no webservice directly running on the server.

Comment: So my Idea, is to
tell ubuntu (master) to forward any 80 or 443 traffic to the externalIP of the
ingress controller (inside the kubernetes cluster) to handel all webrequests
and also forward my specific domain request to the service (ingress rule).

When I got seomthing wrong, please correct me. Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with installing HAProxy on the maschine I want to resole my domain to. HAProxy listens to port 80 and 443 and forwards all trafic to the externalIP of my ingress controller. You can also do this on multiple mashines and DNS failover for high availability.

My haproxy.cfg

```
frontend unsecure
    bind 0.0.0.0:80
    default_backend unsecure_pass

backend unsecure_pass
    server unsecure_pass 198.51.100.0:80



frontend secure
    bind 0.0.0.0:443
    default_backend secure_pass


backend secure_pass
    server secure_pass 198.51.100.0:443
```

Answer (score 1):

Bare-metal cluster are a bit tricky to set-up because you need to create and manage the point of contact to your services. In cloud environment these are available on-demand.

I followed [this doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/) and can assume that your load balancer seems to be working fine as you are able to `curl` this IP address. However, you are trying to get a response when calling a domain. For this you need some app running inside your cluster, which is exposed to hostname via Ingress component.

I'll take you through steps to achieve that.
First, create a Deployment to run a webservice, I'm gonna use simple nginx example:

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Second, create a Service of type LoadBalancer to be able to access it externally. You can do that by simply running this command:
`kubectl expose deployment nginx-deployment --type=LoadBalancer --name=<service_name>`
If your software load balancer is set up correctly, this should give external IP address to the Deployment you created before.

Last but not least, create [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) service which will manage external access and name-based virtual hosting. Example:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: <ingress_name>
spec:
  rules:
    - host: <your_domain>
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: <service_name>
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Now, you should be able to use your domain name as an external access to your cluster.